# Resizing images in nivoslider

Tags: javascript, css, image, resize, nivo-slider

I have problem with image sizes. I am using a nivoslider. I set width and height in CSS by this:

```
.nivoSlider img {
width:688px !important;
height:324px !important;
```

It works when I upload a image with width:688px and height:324px but when I upload a image with other size it will not set that dimension.

You can look at this page http://www.zsmltu.cz/2014/ and check the slider.

Js file is here http://pastebin.com/NMNqT2ui

Could you tell me how can I change the JS file to resize image to width:688px and height:324px

Comment: You should isolate the problem in a jsfiddle instead of linking to your website.  This way, after your issue is solved, people can still learn from your question.

Comment: Just to add to Alexander's comment, your site may change or go down in the future, and having your issue up on a fiddle will help future users who run into a similar issue.

Comment: It is pretty hard to simulate the problem in jsfiddle :/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.nivoSlider img { 
width:688px !important; 
height:324px !important;
```

WITH

```
.nivoSlider img { 
width: 688px; 
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: how about making both height and width just to auto; see my updated answer. OR leave width:688px and height:auto;

Comment: Still the same. I would say the problem is somewhere in JS. Ive tried pretty much possibilites in CSS and nothing helped.

Comment: final attempt .. see update answer. Make sure to clear the CSS cache

Comment: Indeed. I have tried many things and now I have absolutelly no idea what to do. Maybe some js way to resize the image?

Comment: Do you have an element with class `nivoSlider` in the HTML body?

Comment: It is not exactly in HTML but in that JS file. You can look with console for developer.